# How I can provide arguments towards the existing graphql request?

Tags: magento2.4, graphql

I made the followig `schema.graphqls`

```
type BlogPost {
    blog_post_id: ID
    title: String
    post: String
}

input BlogpostAttributeFilterInput {
    page: Int
    limit: Int
}

type Query {
    allBlogPosts(input: BlogpostAttributeFilterInput) :
    [BlogPost] @resolver(class: "\\MageGuide\\FirstModule\\Model\\Resolver\\GetBlogPosts")
    @doc(description:"Retrieve All BlogPosts")
    @cache(cacheable: false)
}
```

And I want to provide some arguments towards the request `allBlogPosts` I tried in my tool:

```
{
    allBlogPosts(page:1,limit:10){
        blog_post_id
    title
        post
  }
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Unknown argument \"page\" on field \"allBlogPosts\" of type \"Query\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 15
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "message": "Unknown argument \"limit\" on field \"allBlogPosts\" of type \"Query\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 22
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How I can provide the arguments towards the request?

Comment: Please post your resolver file